# Show that v is the sum of Im(f) and Ker(f)

Tags: linear-algebra

If  $P:V\rightarrow V$ is a linear such that $P^2 = P$ show  that $V=\ker(P) + \operatorname{im}(P)$

I've seen this proof:

$$x \in V $$

$$x=\underbrace{(x-p(x))}_{\in\ker p}+\underbrace{p(x)}_{\in \operatorname{im} p}$$

But I dont understand why we can say that $\underbrace{(x-p(x))}_{\in\ker p}$ and that $\underbrace{p(x)}_{\in \operatorname{im} p}$.

Comment: It isnot true, suppose $p=$ integral operation. it is true for $p^2=p$

Comment: This question is definitely lacking context.

Comment: I think you are missing the assumption that $P^2=P$.

Comment: Do you at least understand why $p(x) \in \operatorname{im} p$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(x)$ is element of the image of $P$ as it is defined as $\operatorname{im}(P) = \{P(x)|x\in V\}$.

$x-P(x)$ is in the kernel as $P(x-P(x)) = P(x) - P(P(x)) = 0$ holds by linearity of $P$.

Answer (score 0):

of course $p(x)\in \mathrm{im}\ p$ by the definition of $\mathrm{im}\ p$. To see why $(x-p(x)) \in \mathrm{ker}\ p$, just apply $p$ to $x-p(x)$ and because we have $p^{2}=p$, and by the definition of $\mathrm{ker}\ p$, we will see that it must be happened.